# Why two vectors cannot span ${\bf R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider two vectors 
$$
u_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
 3 \\
 2 \\
\end{bmatrix},\quad
u_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
 6 \\ 
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can tell they don't span $R^3$ because $R^3$ requires three vectors to span it.

But is there *another* way I can see that it does not span $R^3$, for example, in terms of overdetermined system, or not a square matrix? Just trying to develop a mature understanding of this topic, that's all.

Comment: you could find a vector orthogonal to both.

Comment: Finding an orthogonal vector to both would then find me a spanning set, and thus, these two do not span the $R^3$. Oh yeah, I will have to find out how to find orthogonal vector. I suppose I would just do a cross-product.

Comment: Aahh, nice edit @Jack. I was actually trying to work out how to do what you did when I first wrote the question. I will remember that...\quad and keep them both within the same set of dollar signs. Cheers.

Comment: For the square matrix: if you try and express the vectors as columns in an augmented matrix to solve a system of equations, with target variables k as your last column, then you will indeed find the dimensions of the matrix don't match up nicely -- I can make a follow-up answer later

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to find $(a,b,c)$ such that $(a,b,c)$ cannot be written as $x(-1,3,2)+y(6,1,1)$. But this is easy -- in fact, since *most* $(a,b,c)$ cannot be written in that way, you can just pick one at random and start solving!

For example, pick $(a,b,c)=(0,0,1)$.

Since $-x+6y=0$ we must have $x=6y$. Now plug that into $3x+y=0$, giving $18y+y=0$ which is the same as $19y=0$, and so $y=0$.

But then $x=y=0$ and $x(-1,3,3)+y(6,1,1)=(0,0,0)$, which is not what we wanted. So $(0,0,1)$ is impossible to make, and thus we have the counterexample we need.

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$. Let us see if $u\in\langle u_1,u_2\rangle$. It is true if and only if there are $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that $u=xu_1+yu_2$, which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-x+6y=a\\3x+y=b\\2x+y=c\end{array}\right.$$If you try to solve the system, you will see that, for some values of $a$, $b$, and $c$; it has no solution. Therefore, $\langle u_1,u_2\rangle\neq\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of question I'm asking. how do you know that this system will not be consistent for some <a,b,c>? Is it because there are less unknowns than equations that you know this immediately? @Jose

Comment: @Bucephalus When there are less unknowns than equations, there is always at least one combination $\lambda_1 E_1 + \lambda_2 E_2 + \lambda_3 E_3$ of the equations which LHS is equal to $0$ and some $\lambda_i$ are not equal to zero. If you choose for example $(a, b, c) = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)$, you obtain an inconsistent equation $0 =$ some non zero constant.

Comment: @Bucephalus The system formed by the first two equations either has one and only one solution for each $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ or not. If it has, then you choose $c$ such that the system becomes inconsistent. Otherwise, there will be some $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ for which the system formed by the first two equations already has no solution.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 3):

$\dim\operatorname{span}(\{v_1,v_2\}) \le 2$ while $\dim(\mathbb{R}^n) = n$ for all $n$.

Comment: I thought I basically stated this in my opening question.

Comment: @Bucephalus You didn't  mention dimension. Dimension was invented to make questions like this easy to answer.

Comment: Fair comment @HennoBrandsma. I didn't explicitly say it and dim allows us to use less words for sure. Thanks for your effort. Cheers.