# Geometrical explanation / visualisation as to why 2 vectors cannot span R3?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, visualization

I have already understood as to why 2 vectors cannot span R3 in a simple algebraic manner. This is from an answer to this very question 3 years ago :
[Why two vectors cannot span ${\bf R}^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407569/why-two-vectors-cannot-span-bf-r3)

However, I would like to visualise as to why it is so. I have tried visualizing in my mind as well as drawing by hand in whatever way possible, but still can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Suppose you lived on a flat plain and can only move North-South or East-West. Then you'll never be able to leave the ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are drawing two vectors, you are probably doing it on a planar object, possibly a sheet of paper. Now, use an appropriate parallelogram, similar to the one they teach you when you learn how to add vectors, to draw any linear combination of these two vectors (assuming they are not collinear, which if they are - they certainly span just a line). Notice that all such parallelograms remain in the same plane where you had drawn the two vectors. Conclusion: Every pair of (linearly independent) vectors span a plane.

Comment: I think your answer makes the most sense to me. I had read almost a same kind of reasoning minutes after I posted this question. I think its easier to visualize/understand when drawing 2 vectors on an 2D plane such as a paper. But the reasoning can be translated to 3D too. I had initially tried drawing 2 vectors in a 3D coordinate system on my whiteboard which led me to be confused as to how a plane could just go through both any 2 vectors drawn in the 3D space. Thank you for your prompt and clear answer.

Comment: @Joshua Mathew Jacob  You are welcome !

Comment: @JoshuaMathewJacob To put it yet another way: every pair of straight lines in $\mathbb R^3$ necessarily forms/specifies/spans a plane. This includes the pair that you drew on the aforementioned paper, which is just a 2D plane that exists in 3D space $(\mathbb R^3)$.

Comment: @RyanG Yes thank you for this perspective too. I'm welcome to all ways of understanding the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Any vector that lies in the linear subspace spanned by two vectors lies in a plane (the one spanned by the two vectors). You get the desired result as $\mathbb R^3$ is not included in a plane.